# Glassfish server 3.1 shuts down itself

Tags: java, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

Glassfish server 3.1  is running on Amazon cloud. It shuts down itself after some time. What could be the reason?

I have to manually start the server using `asadmin` command each and every time. I want to keep it alive for very long time.

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see what's going on? Any error/exception/message in there?

Comment: Instead of running the start command from `asadmin` shell, ie, instead of typing `asadmin` & hitting enter at the shell, then typing `start-domain domainXyz`; run the command from the shell itself `asadmin start-domain domainXyz`.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no reason for Glassfish just to "shut itself down".  Unlike Tomcat, I'm pretty sure Glassfish doesn't have a shutdown port.

You should check /glassfish/domains/[domainname]/logs for any log information that may have an exception or similar.  If you could provide these logs (with an appropriate error) we would probably be able to help you further.

The fact it's using Amazon EC2 should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
[Glassfish 4 server stops unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079951/glassfish-4-server-stops-unexpectedly)
The RAM Could be the issue. and the JVM ran out of Memory