# Glassfish 4 server stops unexpectedly

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, glassfish, application-server, glassfish-4

I'm new to GlassFish, and to application servers in general. I have an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu and have installed GlassFish 4. It starts up without problems, but after a while the GlassFish server just shuts down all by itself. I have looked through server.log, but everything seems normal, and there are no entries describing any failures or shut down. Any input on what can be the cause, or where I should look to find any clues?

Comment: have you found any solutions for this, I'm facing the exact same problem. on amazon EC2 linux image.

Comment: @KarimIhab Sorry, no. I'm afraid studies came in the way. I am going to continue working on this project when I get time, hopefully during this vacation (in a couple of weeks). But since you're actively looking for a solution right now, would you mind posting an answer or a link in the comments here if you find out anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I am facing the exact same situation. I suspected the reason was that JVM ran out of RAM, as the free EC2 instance has a niggard 600 MB (`cat /proc/meminfo` to verify). To look for clues I turned on JVM logging for Glassfish domain, in order to do so I added the following lines to JVM parameters in `<domain>/config/domain.xml`:

```
<jvm-options>-XX:LogFile=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/jvm.log</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+LogVMOutput</jvm-options>
```

Later when Glassfish shut down, the `jvm.log` contained lots of messages like the following:

```
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' x='java/util/ArrayList iterator ()Ljava/util/Iterator;' witness='javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase$ChildrenList' stamp='13211.267'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' x='java/util/ArrayList iterator ()Ljava/util/Iterator;' witness='javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase$ChildrenList' stamp='13211.267'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' x='java/util/ArrayList iterator ()Ljava/util/Iterator;' witness='javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase$ChildrenList' stamp='13211.267'/>
```

I never found out what they really meant, but I'm posting them here in case someone takes the same road as me and googles for them.

Then finally I looked in `/var/log/syslog` (the one I found was actually named `syslog.1`), and voila! I got the confirmation that JVM process ran out of memory and was killed:

```
Dec 20 07:44:44 ip-172-31-33-222 kernel: [1518108.211801] Out of memory: Kill process 22248 (java) score 743 or sacrifice child
Dec 20 07:44:44 ip-172-31-33-222 kernel: [1518108.211833] Killed process 22248 (java) total-vm:1622220kB, anon-rss:447752kB, file-rss:0kB
```

It seems to me that increasing swap space should fix the problem. It turns out on EC2 swap space is 0 by default, so I allocated 1 GB, see [How do you add swap to an EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance)

The server used to crash on a daily basis, but with swap on it hasn't crashed in weeks.

Comment: Great, I will test this solution for a week or two and post the results here. @Hunternif